# Wrong datetime saved a GCP Datastore .net

Tags: .net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a .netcore service deployed on GCP that saves entities in GCP Datastore database. Entities have a Datetime property but dates are not being saved correctly. As GCP Datastore stands, I do set all date properties in entities as UTC dates but when saving the entities it seems that date properties are adding timezone offset. For example, I have saved an entity with a property "createdAt": "2020-06-10 10:36:00.000z" and when I navigate to Datastore GCP console I can see it has been saved as "2020-06-10 (14:36:30.000) CEST".

Any Idea?

***EDIT***

To clarify my example, my local time was  "2020-06-10 (12:36:30.000) CEST". As Datastore.V1 net client requires, I converted the time to UTC so it's "2020-06-10 10:36:00.000z" but it was stored as "2020-06-10 (14:36:30.000) CEST".

This date comes from an email read from GMail API, it's the email's reception date.

The service is running in an App Engine application hosted at Frankfurt (europe-west-3). The funny thing is that if I run the service locally in my labtop the date is saved fine ?!?!?!?

Comment: can you share a code snipet of the function that you are using to save the date? by default App Engine has a UTC time, I want to try replicate this issue on my side.

Comment: We finally decided to move to PostgresQL. GCP Datastore is great but it has some querying limitations we can easily by pass

Answer (score 0):

The GCP console is converting your UTC date to your local date, for example try to [crete a new test entity](https://console.google.com/datastore/entities/new)

Add a property of type "Date and Time" select a date and time with GTM/UTC as time zone.

Add Another property, at this point the card of the first property will be collapsed and should show the previous property value in Local time